# how to change Application.StartupPath on run time in Winform using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, startup

I have a winform application which has 21 video files and they'e path is set as applicaton.startupPath like this ...

```
vpath[0] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v00.m4v";
        vpath[1] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v01.m4v";
        vpath[2] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v02.m4v";
        vpath[3] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v03.m4v";
        vpath[4] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v04.m4v";
        vpath[5] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v05.m4v";
        vpath[6] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v06.m4v";
        vpath[7] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v07.m4v";
        vpath[8] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v08.m4v";
        vpath[9] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v09.m4v";
        vpath[10] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v10.m4v";
        vpath[11] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v11.m4v";
        vpath[12] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v12.m4v";
        vpath[13] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v13.m4v";
        vpath[14] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v14.m4v";
        vpath[15] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v15.m4v";
        vpath[16] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v16.m4v";
        vpath[17] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v17.m4v";
        vpath[18] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v18.m4v";
        vpath[19] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v19.m4v";
        vpath[20] = Application.StartupPath + @"\v20.m4v";
```

now if a user wants to change those videos then he have to name it as v00 to v20. now if a user add video with different format then how can i change the path?? is it possible to change it on run time? if yes then how??

Comment: What is this ? "if a user wants to change those videos then he have to name it as v00 to v20"

Comment: yes. bcoz i am setting the application.startuppath like that. my question is can i set the application.startuppath on the run time for this many videos ??

Comment: Off course you can do almost anything at runtime. e.g. `vpath[19] = Application.StartupPath + @"\abc.flv";` is this what you want?

Comment: i am already doing this. what i want is user will include a video and it will be taken as application.startuopath

Comment: Share your code of video addition by user and I will add the path. If you don't want to share for any reason then : if you are using array of strings, use List of strings instead and on adding a video by user just increase your list as `list.Add(Application.StartupPath + @"\v"+list.count+"."+userFileName.Split('.')[userFileName.Split('.').Length-1]` you will this value in `list[21]` as `Application.StartupPath + @"\vListcount.extention";`

Comment: I have not written it in answer because I am sorry, I have been still unable to understand your question well. Its just a guess by comments that you are expecting something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StartupPath` is not a regular variable. In fact, it is not variable at all and also it cannot be "written", it is a get-only property.

Actually, you can change that property result value by copying the main executable file into required directory and re-runing it from there, but what's th point?

Navigate to [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx), [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) and [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) classes to learn how to play with the file system.

Answer (score 0):

you can add another variable to your code

```
public string VideoPath;
```

initialize it with

```
VideoPath = Application.StartupPath;
```

and than change it as you wish

Comment: if you describe your needs in other words, I'll try to help